# Pick a [*-side]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Should [client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-side) and [server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-side) go? Seems very meta to me when there are plenty of other more specific tags that could be used instead.
Thoughts?

Comment: I picked client side

Comment: I'm getting an Ali G vibe here

Comment: Merge them. That'll be fun.

Comment: *Neither. I'm your ad-injecting ISP* /s

Comment: Suggested title: Should we homicide [client-side] and [server-side]?

Comment: Fun numbers: despite either tag having almost 2k question, most of the top users have just 1 answer to questions with the tag.

Comment: As an aside, I really enjoy all sides of these puns.

Comment: I think there are very fine sides on both sides...

Comment: @CameronTaylor I hope you don't mean "many sides".

Comment: Many sides have many eyes. Beware.

Comment: If you removed both of them, would they be [*-side] burns?

Comment: Suggested title: de[-side]

Comment: Explicit Reference is far better than implication. Having an extra segregator poses no harm.

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar: So we should tag this meta question with [burninate] [remove-existing-tag] [community-effort] [cleanup] [specific-tag] [open-for-debate]? More tags != better.

Comment: I'll choose the dark side

Answer (score 11):

The main argument for the burnination of this tag is its redundancy.

---

#### 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does, but never any more than a more specific, more applicable tag for that particular question would.

#### 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, as long as it refers to the software aspect and not the hardware.

#### 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

This is a big heaping **NO**. For example, a question tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) will imply that it is a question about a client-side application (most of the time), and so the [client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-side) is not needed. More specifics can be brought on with more tags appropriate to that specific situation (such as [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)).

#### 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Yes, since both tags refer to Web applications, and from what I've seen, every question seems to use it in this context.

Comment: *“a question tagged javascript will imply that it is a question about a client-side application (most of the time)”* – You already gave the exception there; note that Node is not the only environment that would allow you to run JS on a server. Also note that with wasm, classic non-client-web stuff will eventually move to the browser as well.

Comment: @poke The point of this is to explain the redundancy of the tag, not to claim that I have expertise in JS, which I don't...

Comment: I’m just saying for a *“big heaping NO”*, your arguments are pretty bad considering you end up weakening them up yourself. – A more solid reasoning would be that neither tag would make sense on its own, so it will be always accompanied by other tags which should give enough context as to what the question is about. And questions that would only have on of the `*-side` tags would be very likely either too broad or highly subjective (e.g. “how to do this and that on the client-side”).

Comment: @poke Which I mentioned `More specifics can be brought on with more tags appropriate to that specific situation` implying that these tags on their own were too broad to provide any real contextual meaning.

Comment: “a question tagged javascript will imply that it is a question about a client-side application (most of the time)”  It 'implies' but it isn't an explicit reference. Having an extra segregate poses no harm.

Comment: In my opinion, those tags could be useful sometimes. Consider a web application that wants to migrate key stretching to the client. The code posted might be partially server side to illustrate the current implementation and partially client side to illustrate the attempt, but it really is a `[client-side]` question. Also, consider client-side versus server-side caching for certain applications. It might add some context sometimes.

Comment: A question only tagged [[tag:javascript]] for language is absolutely client-side. If it were server-side, the [[tag:node.js]] would be mandatory. Lacking the node tag, the question is client-side. The [*-side] tag is absolutely redundant.

Comment: "Yes, since both tags refer to Web application", so what about technologies such as WCF? It is not a "web" application since it can be used for desktop applications. WCF can cause problems server-side and client-side, and they can be wildly different

Comment: @Cerbrus: Do you mean that you cannot under any circumstances write server-side javascript without node.js?!

Comment: @Burkhard: I mean that you can''t write server-side js without a server-side js specific tag, making the "server-side" tag redundant.

Comment: @Cerbrus you are implying that a user cannot write their own server-side js code. I wonder then how node was created...

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Node was created by using Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. It is written in C/C++. Node.js isn't written in JavaScript. So no, you can't write server-side JS without a server-side JS interpreter which would be a mandatory tag.

Comment: What I am saying is: if someone is writing server-side JS, there _will be_ a (required) interpreter or library tag for it that makes [server-side] redundant.