# Maybe [client-scripting] should take a walk on the [client-side]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I notice [client-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-scripting) has 20 mostly rather old questions on a wide range of topics. I'd suggest that this be **merged** with the broader [client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-side), as most of the 20 have a more specific tag ([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom), [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser) etc) anyway.

Comment: I think the client-side tag is also a rather bad one, as well as the server-side tag. But as they contain around 2000 questions each they would need separate meta questions to burn

Comment: i asked to burn client and server side. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355654/pick-a-side